# DMedian in access 2013, no values returned

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have the following query in MS Access 2013 than does not return a Median value.

The field IU is always NULL (blank) or 1. Column GM is a number formatted 0.0000 between -5 and 5 with NULL values in it occasionally.

```
SELECT IU, DMedian("GM","tblFirst250","IU=1") AS MedianByIU
FROM tblFirst250
WHERE IU = 1
GROUP BY IU;
```

However, while attempting to debug this, when I use DAvg instead of DMedian I get an Average value.

I got DMedian (because I understood that Access 2013 didn't have it) from:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd789431(v=office.12).aspx

Here is the code I have in a module called basDMedian as part of my database:

```vb
Public Function DMedian( _
 ByVal strField As String, ByVal strDomain As String, _
 Optional ByVal strCriteria As String) As Variant

    ' Purpose:
    '     To calculate the median value
    '     for a field in a table or query.
    ' In:
    '     strField: the field.
    '     strDomain: the table or query.
    '     strCriteria: an optional WHERE clause to
    '                  apply to the table or query.
    ' Out:
    '     Return value: the median, if successful;
    '                   Otherwise, an Error value.

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rstDomain As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim varMedian As Variant
    Dim intFieldType As Integer
    Dim intRecords As Integer

    Const errAppTypeError = 3169

    On Error GoTo HandleErr

    Set db = CurrentDb()

    ' Initialize return value.
    varMedian = Null

    ' Build SQL string for recordset.
    strSQL = "SELECT " & strField & " FROM " & strDomain

    ' Only use a WHERE clause if one is passed in.
    If Len(strCriteria) > 0 Then
        strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE " & strCriteria
    End If

    strSQL = strSQL & " ORDER BY " & strField

    Set rstDomain = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)

    ' Check the data type of the median field.
    intFieldType = rstDomain.Fields(strField).Type
    Select Case intFieldType
    Case dbByte, dbInteger, dbLong, _
      dbCurrency, dbSingle, dbDouble, dbDate
        ' Numeric field.
        If Not rstDomain.EOF Then
            rstDomain.MoveLast
            intRecords = rstDomain.RecordCount
            ' Start from the first record.
            rstDomain.MoveFirst

            If (intRecords Mod 2) = 0 Then
                ' Even number of records.
                ' No middle record, so move to the
                ' record right before the middle.
                rstDomain.Move ((intRecords \ 2) - 1)
                varMedian = rstDomain.Fields(strField)
                ' Now move to the next record, the
                ' one right after the middle.
                rstDomain.MoveNext
                ' And average the two values.
                varMedian = _
                  (varMedian + rstDomain.Fields(strField)) / 2
                ' Make sure you return a date, even when
                ' averaging two dates.
                If intFieldType = dbDate And Not IsNull(varMedian) Then
                    varMedian = CDate(varMedian)
                End If
            Else
                ' Odd number or records.
                ' Move to the middle record and return its value.
                rstDomain.Move ((intRecords \ 2))
                varMedian = rstDomain.Fields(strField)
            End If
        Else
            ' No records; return Null.
            varMedian = Null
        End If
    Case Else
        ' Non-numeric field; so raise an app error.
        Err.Raise errAppTypeError
    End Select

    DMedian = varMedian

ExitHere:
    On Error Resume Next
    rstDomain.Close
    Set rstDomain = Nothing
    Exit Function

HandleErr:
    ' Return an error value.
    DMedian = CVErr(Err.Number)
    Resume ExitHere
End Function
```

My objective is to get a Median value of the GM column of the records that have IU = 1. The value I get is NULL/blank. If there is a better approach, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: What do you get from this in the Immediate window? `Debug.Print DMedian("GM","tblFirst250","IU=1 AND GM Is Not Null")`  (Ctrl+g will take you to the Immediate window.)

Comment: @HansUp - I get 1.15926538913139

Comment: @HansUp - This works! Post the answer and I'll check it answered.
SELECT IU, DMedian("GM","tblFirst250","IU=1 AND GM Is Not Null") AS MedianByIU
FROM tblFirst250
WHERE IU = 1
GROUP BY IU;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask your `DMedian` expression to ignore any Nulls in the *GM* field.

```sql
SELECT IU, DMedian("GM","tblFirst250","IU=1 AND GM Is Not Null") AS MedianByIU
FROM tblFirst250
WHERE IU = 1
GROUP BY IU;
```

Basically what happened is `DMedian` opened a recordset sorted by *GM* and then moved (roughly) half way through the recordset to get the median value.  But if the value in that row happened to be Null ...

```
GM
--
Null
Null  <- median
2
```

... `DMedian` told you the median is Null.  So instructing `DMedian` to load only rows where `GM Is Not Null` gave you the median of the non-Null values.