# How to create percentile function for a SQL query in MS Access that allows GROUP BY and filtering?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I'm attempting to write a domain function I can use in MS Access SQL view like what is found here: [DMedian in access 2013, no values returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736739/dmedian-in-access-2013-no-values-returned)

...but for a DPercentile function that allows you to GROUP BY and filter.

This is what I have so far:

```vb
Public Function DPercentileWithGrpBy( _
 ByVal sFld As String, _
 ByVal sTable As String, _
 ByVal iPercent As Integer, _
 ByVal sGrpByFld As String, _
 ByVal sGrpByValue As String _
 ) As Variant


    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rstDomain As DAO.Recordset
    Dim sSQL As String

    Const errAppTypeError = 3169

    On Error GoTo HandleErr

    Set db = CurrentDb()

    ' Build SQL string for recordset.
    sSQL = "SELECT " & _
                sTable & "." & sGrpByFld & _
                "," & (1 - iPercent / 100) & "*(" & _
                    "SELECT Max(" & sFld & ") " & _
                    "FROM " & sTable & " " & _
                    "WHERE " & sTable & "." & sFld & " IN (" & _
                        "SELECT TOP " & iPercent & " PERCENT " & sFld & " " & _
                        "FROM " & sTable & " " & _
                        "WHERE " & sTable & "." & sGrpByFld & " = " & Chr(34) & sGrpByValue & Chr(34) & " AND " & sFld & " Is Not Null ORDER BY " & sFld & ")) + " & iPercent / 100 & "*(" & _
                            "SELECT Min(" & sFld & ") " & _
                            "FROM " & sTable & " " & _
                            "WHERE " & sTable & "." & sFld & " IN (" & _
                                "SELECT TOP " & 100 - iPercent & " PERCENT " & sFld & " " & _
                                "FROM " & sTable & " " & _
                                "WHERE " & sTable & "." & sGrpByFld & " = " & Chr(34) & sGrpByValue & Chr(34) & " AND " & sFld & " Is Not Null ORDER BY " & sFld & " DESC)" & _
                ") AS " & iPercent & "Percentile " & _
                "FROM " & sTable & " " & _
                "WHERE " & sTable & "." & sGrpByFld & " = " & Chr(34) & sGrpByValue & Chr(34) & " " & _
                "GROUP BY " & sTable & "." & sGrpByFld & ";"
'Debug.Print sSQL

'above should result in something like this:
'SELECT
 ' tblFirst250.[GICS Sector]
'  , 0.75*(
  '  SELECT Max(GM)
  '  FROM tblFirst250
  '  WHERE tblFirst250.GM IN (
   '   SELECT TOP 25 PERCENT GM
   '   FROM tblFirst250
    '  WHERE tblFirst250.[GICS Sector] = "Energy" AND GM Is Not Null ORDER BY GM)) + 0.25*(
     '   SELECT Min(GM)
     '   FROM tblFirst250
     '   WHERE tblFirst250.GM IN (
    '      SELECT TOP 75 PERCENT GM
   '       FROM tblFirst250
  '        WHERE tblFirst250.[GICS Sector] = "Energy" AND GM Is Not Null ORDER BY GM DESC)
 ' ) AS 25Percentile
'FROM tblFirst250
'WHERE tblFirst250.[GICS Sector] = "Energy"
'GROUP BY tblFirst250.[GICS Sector];

    Set rstDomain = db.OpenRecordset(sSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

     DPercentileWithGrpBy = rstDomain

ExitHere:
    On Error Resume Next
    rstDomain.Close
    Set rstDomain = Nothing
    Exit Function

HandleErr:
    ' Return an error value.
    DPercentileWithGrpBy = CVErr(Err.Number)
    Resume ExitHere
End Function
```

I'd like to have the ability to use the function in MS Access SQL View as a query or part of a query. I also need to do a percentile (quartiles) of a sub group of records. Hopefully that make sense...

EDIT: the resulting query works when I debug.print it and using it in SQL View.

EDIT: here is how you could use it:

```vb
DPercentileWithGrpBy( "GM","tblFirst250", 25,"[GICS Sector]","Energy")
```

Comment: Sorry, I totally misread your intent. Do you receive any errors?

Comment: Yes, it seems that in simplifying my code for the post I created a syntax error. I'll fix and repost. Sorry about that.

Comment: I take that back. No, I do not get a compile error. I thought I did, but it compiles fine. It was something else I was working on...

Comment: Okay, so does it work?

Comment: No, not in SQL View. I get a type mismatch.

Comment: @Hansup - are you there? :)

Comment: For anyone else looking at this the Debug.Print comes out with this: `SELECT tblFirst250.[GICS Sector],0.75*(SELECT Max(GM) FROM tblFirst250 WHERE tblFirst250.GM IN (SELECT TOP 25 PERCENT GM FROM tblFirst250 WHERE tblFirst250.[GICS Sector] = "Energy" AND GM Is Not Null ORDER BY GM)) + 0.25*(SELECT Min(GM) FROM tblFirst250 WHERE tblFirst250.GM IN (SELECT TOP 75 PERCENT GM FROM tblFirst250 WHERE tblFirst250.[GICS Sector] = "Energy" AND GM Is Not Null ORDER BY GM DESC)) AS 25Percentile FROM tblFirst250 WHERE tblFirst250.[GICS Sector] = "Energy" GROUP BY tblFirst250.[GICS Sector];`

Comment: @Newd - I think that is in the comments in my question....

Comment: @mountainclimber I figured, but it looks edited.  I find edited strings can often be misleading when trying to find out what is wrong (fixed or caused in the edit).