# Having a problem creating/running a query to solve a Median value function

Tags: sql, vba, function

This my first attempt to pose a question to stackoverflow so please forgive if it is submitted incorrectly or is otherwise out-of-line

As a novice programmer of VBA, I am attempting to create and run a query to execute a User-created function to create a query with a Median()  result.

I shamelessly plagiarized a Stack Overflow suggested answer for the VBA function.
[how to calculate median in Access query using function in VBa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56241793/how-to-calculate-median-in-access-query-using-function-in-vba)
See below for my version.

The only changes to that function were to change the fieldname, the input query name and removal of the Optional function statements as it did not apply to my dataset.

The SQL view of the query "qryMedian" is:

```
SELECT tblNewOhioAllMedian.AOU2020, tblNewOhioAllMedian.number1, acbdMedian([Number1],"qryMedian") AS MedianResults
FROM tblNewOhioAllMedian
ORDER BY tblNewOhioAllMedian.AOU2020, tblNewOhioAllMedian.number1;
```

tblNewOhioAllMedian is the originating table
AOU2020 is defined as a double number
Number1 is an integer number
acbdMedian is the user-defined function

Both the Query and Function compiled correctly, but either the query or function is not setup right and/or the results are not being passed between the two.

Any help in resolving my issue would be much appreciated.

The function run was the Stack Overflow suggestion modified as above with my changes:

```vb
Public Function acbdMedian( _
 ByVal Number1 As String, ByVal qryMedian As String) As Variant
    ' Purpose:
    '     To calculate the median value
    '     for a field in a table or query.
    ' In:
    '     Number1: The field
    '     qryMedian: The table or query
    '     strCriteria: An optional WHERE clause to
    '                  apply to the table or query
' strCriteria value removed as not applicable

    ' Out:
    '     Return value: The median, if successful;
    '                   otherwise, an error value

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rstDomain As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim varMedian As Variant
    Dim intFieldType As Integer
    Dim intRecords As Integer
    Const acbcErrAppTypeError = 3169

    On Error GoTo HandleErr

    Set db = CurrentDb()

    ' Initialize the return value.
    varMedian = Null

    ' Build a SQL string for the recordset.
    strSQL = "SELECT " & Number1
    strSQL = strSQL & " FROM " & qryMedian

' Use a WHERE clause only if one is passed in.
'If Len(strCriteria) > 0 Then
'strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE " & strCriteria
'End If

    strSQL = strSQL & " ORDER BY " & Number1

    Set rstDomain = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)

    ' Check the data type of the median field.
    intFieldType = rstDomain.Fields(Number1).Type
    Select Case intFieldType
    Case dbByte, dbInteger, dbLong, dbCurrency, dbSingle, dbDouble, dbDate
        ' Numeric field.
        If Not rstDomain.EOF Then
            rstDomain.MoveLast
            intRecords = rstDomain.RecordCount
            ' Start from the first record.
            rstDomain.MoveFirst

            If (intRecords Mod 2) = 0 Then
                ' Even number of records. No middle record, so move
                ' to the record right before the middle.
                rstDomain.Move ((intRecords \ 2) - 1)
                varMedian = rstDomain.Fields(Number1)
                ' Now move to the next record, the one right after
                ' the middle.
                rstDomain.MoveNext
                ' Average the two values.
                varMedian = (varMedian + rstDomain.Fields(Number1)) / 2
                ' Make sure you return a date, even when averaging
                ' two dates.
                If intFieldType = dbDate And Not IsNull(varMedian) Then
                    varMedian = CDate(varMedian)
                End If
            Else
                ' Odd number of records. Move to the middle record
                ' and return its value.
                rstDomain.Move ((intRecords \ 2))
                varMedian = rstDomain.Fields(Number1)
            End If
        Else
            ' No records; return Null.
            varMedian = Null
        End If
    Case Else
        ' Nonnumeric field; raise an app error.
        Err.Raise acbcErrAppTypeError
    End Select

    acbdMedian = varMedian
ExitHere:
    On Error Resume Next
    rstDomain.Close
    Set rstDomain = Nothing
    Exit Function

HandleErr:
    ' Return an error value.
    acbdMedian = CVErr(Err)
    Resume ExitHere
End Function
```

Results of running the Select Query:

```
AOU 2020     number1     MedianResults
    10  1   #Error
    10  1   #Error
    10  1   #Error
    10  1   #Error
        ETC
```

This query ran very slow and would have taken hours
To complete the 240,000 records at that rate

My interpretation of the results:
Each entry is a separate record with the results of the function being #Error
No Medians were calculated.

Here is the latest test table:

```
AOU2020 Number1
1   1
2   1
20  2
10  2
1   2
2   2
20  3
20  3
10  3
10  3
1   3
2   3
10  50
10  50
10  50
10  50
10  50
10  50
10  50
10  50
10  50
10  50
20  60
10  60
20  100
10  100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have field in table named Number1? Fieldname must be within quote marks in function argument.

Cannot pass same query name that function is called in.

If you want a median for each AOU2020 group, then need to pass filter criteria to function. Modify function declaration:

```
Public Function acbdMedian( _
 ByVal Number1 As String, ByVal qryMedian As String, Optional ByVal strCriteria As String) As Variant
```

Uncomment 3 lines concerning criteria by removing the leading apostrophe:

```
If Len(strCriteria) > 0 Then
strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE " & strCriteria
End If
```

To return one record for each AOU2020, use aggregate query.
qryMedian:

```
SELECT AOU2020, acbdMedian("Number1", "tblNewOhioAllMedian", "AOU2020=" & [AOU2020]) AS MedianResults
FROM tblNewOhioAllMedian
GROUP BY AOU2020;
```

Results with given sample data:

```
AOU2020 MR
 1      2
 2      2
10      50
20      3
```

Note that because function is declared as Variant type, median value will default to string and left align.

Comment: I copied the above into the SQL view of qryMedian, but when executed it gave me a type mismatch message. I replaced the quotes "" around the numeric field Number1 and the query executed but the results were the same as above i.e. a "#Error" in the MedianResults field.  Is the SQL working, but there is some error in the rest of the function()?

Comment: First, I failed to mention that I am running ACCESS 2003 and there are over 240K records involved.

Comment: I then renamed the "real" file to the test file name and ran the query. With this execution, I still get the Invalid type error for Number1. Replacing the quotes in the SQL with brackets, allows the query to run but with the #Error return to the MedianResults field.

Comment: This entry should be above the last entry.     I created a test file of 53 records and changed the appropriate file names including quoting the Number1 field in the SQL.  This file worked but the results were not as desired. Each record returned had the real Median for the entire file and not the Median for each AOU2020 number. Futhermore there were 53 records returned. What needs to be changed in the functdion() to get the desired results i.e. a single record for each AOU2020 that contains the correct Median?

Comment: The real file is the 240K file, not the test file.  How do I send a sample file?  Yes there is a field Number1 defined as number type. How do i add the filter criteria? Once I get the AOU2020 filter up and working on the test file, I will address issues with the 240k file

Comment: I like your correct answer table, I used your SQL in the query qryMedian but it gives me an error: wrong number of arguments in function() but I don't know how to change the function to accommodate the field AOU2020 which is the presumed missing one

Comment: Instructions in my edited answer - did you follow them?

Comment: I have since fixed my problem with your help.  Thank you